# Unwrap variable which is not optional?

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I came across these lines of code for a simple calculator app.

```
func processOperation (operation: Operation) {
    if currentOperation != Operation.Empty {
        if runningNumber != "" {
            rightValStr = runningNumber
            runningNumber = ""

            if currentOperation == Operation.Multiply {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! * Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Divide {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! / Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Subtract {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! - Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Add {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! + Double(rightValStr)!)"
            }
```

`leftValStr` is declared as `var leftValStr = ""`

`rightValStr` is also declared as `var rightValStr =""`

I am wondering what the purpose of using "!" in `\(Double(leftValStr)! / Double(rightValStr)!)` is for?
From what I know, "!" is for unwrapping optional. leftValStr and rightValStr here are not declared as Optional so why do we have to unwrap them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `leftValStr` and `rightValStr` are not optionals, you are force unwrapping `Double(leftValStr)` and `Double(rightValStr)` and the result of initializing **Double** with a **String** value can be `nil`.

For example, you can't initialize a Double with a `stackoverflow` String.

If you'd like to make sure that this conversion result is correct you can use an `if let` to avoid force unwrapping, for example:

```
if let leftValDouble = Double(leftValStr) {
    // do your code
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

Please remember that if you force unwrap a `nil` value, your code will crash.

Comment: so i should use force unwrapping when the result can be null?

Comment: @Frankie no, in case the result is nil and force unwrapped, your code will crash. See the guidance in Apple's doc, how to work with Optional, first.

Comment: If you're 100% sure those values will be **valid** numbers only - conditionally yes, but if you let the user paste some values or any other scenario - you should check the result using for example `if let`. And please remember to write some unit tests, this is a perfect use case.

Comment: if i know 100% sure that those values will be valid numbers, could i use `Double(leftValStr)` instead of `Double(leftValStr)!` ? I am still not so clear about when to use force unwrapping. Sorry for troubling you guys so much, I have just started learning Swift for few days.

Comment: No worries, everyone here is willing to help you. :) Ok, **you** are sure that those values will be valid, but the **compiler** is not. All compiler knows is that he gets some String, and the result may be Double or `nil`. So by using the exclamation mark `!` you somehow say: Yes, I'm sure that I provided you a valid String so you will give me a Double. But force unwrapping (`!`) is risky and not a good practice in general so you should check any nullable value before using it in not nullable context.

Comment: I am clear now. Thank you so much for your explanation @KlimczakM. Btw how do you know that the complier is a he? Just joking :). Have a good day :D

Comment: @Frankie if you find this answer helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Double` initializer that you are using is a `failable` initializer, i.e. it might create a `Double` or return `nil`.

**Example**,

**Double("3")**, here "3" can be converted into `Double`, so it returns an optional `Double` value corresponding to 3.

**Double("abc")**, here "abc" cannot be converted into `Double`, so it returns `nil` in this case.

In your code, you are using **Double("")**, which also cannot be converted into `Double`, hence it returns `nil`.

Now, when you `force unwrap` a `nil` value, it will result in runtime exception.

Hence, `Double(leftValStr)!` results in runtime exception.

> Trying to use ! to access a nonexistent optional value triggers a
>   runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil
>   value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

Comment: Consider upvoting if you find the answer useful.

Comment: I have but as I have less than 15 reputations so the vote cast is only recorded. Sorry :(

Comment: hehe..oki..All the best then..:)